# How to fetch data from two tables in SQL and echo data from third table

Tags: javascript, mysql

I have three tables:

This is `student`:

> ID|Student_number|Student_name|Student_surname|Class|Adress|Phone_number

This is `subject`

> ID|Subject_number|Subject_name|Teacher|Date

This is `grades`:

> ID|Student_number|Subject_number|Grade|Date

I need to take `Subject_number`, `Student_number`, and `Class` and show this student's grades (take data from two tables and echo data from the third table).

This is my work:

[image]

The other thing is that I need to take `Student_number` and `Subject` and show whole class grades in last half of the year.

I mainly work on C++, so it's really hard for me to make these whiles and fors in Javascript. Tried a lot of things, nothing worked for me.

Comment: Are you able to modify the SQL query? If so, you should learn about JOINS, it looks like you would want to join Grades on the primary key values of Student and Subject, the grades table is what I refer to as a junction table where it's primary key is composed of two foreign key values, in this case (Student_number, Subject_number)

Comment: Have question about these JOINS: where should I write that JOINS code? in which section of the code? <head>, <body> or <?php>?

Comment: You would need to do JOINS inside the MySQL Query, are you working in the database at all or are you hard coding a sql query in your php?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I'm doing all the coding in my php (in notepad++). Do I need some kind of other program to do the JOINS or notepad++ is good enough?